# Is there a way to grab the FILTER VIEW unique URL using Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I want to send an email with my filter view unique URL but I don't want to hard code the URL. Is there a way in app scripts where I can get the filter view URL using code?! and put it into different Google Sheets. Even when its not my current active sheet.

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getId;

  var url = '';
  url += SS.getUrl();
  url += 'gid='
  url += 'fvid=';
  url += ss.getId;
```

This only gives me the URL to the spreadSheet not the filter view URL which starts with `'fvid='`

Comment: var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getId;

   var url = '';
  url += SS.getUrl();
  url += 'gid='
  url += 'fvid=';
  url += ss.getId;
  This only gives me the url to the spreadSheet not the filter view url which starts with 'fvid='

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFilterViews(){
  // use current sheet name here, or hardcode the sheet name string instead
  const sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()

  const response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(), {
    includeGridData: false,
    "ranges": sheetName,
    "fields":"sheets.filterViews"
  })
  const filterViewUrls = response.sheets[0].filterViews.map(fv=>fvToUrl(fv))
  console.log(filterViewUrls)
}

function fvToUrl(fv){
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${ssId}/edit#gid=${fv.range.getSheetId()}&fvid=${fv.filterViewId}`
  return url
}
```

If you want a specific filter view ('cat' as an example), you can use

```
const TITLE = 'cat'
const filterViewUrls = response.sheets[0].filterViews.filter(fv=>fv.title===TITLE).map(fv=>fvToUrl(fv))
```

Comment: How would i get the url for a specific filter view name? say the the spread sheet ha 10 filters I only want the url of the filter view named "cat" and not the other filter urls

Comment: could show me how to get a specific filter view name like "cat" in a sheet with that code

Comment: there are multiple options, I updated the answer with one of them @Junior